# Use ACF checkbox value array to find "More like this"

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using an ACF checkbox to designate categories (called "aims") for Psychology apps/sites. So values would be, say, "Mindfulness", "Well-Being" and "Depression".

Since it's possible to select multiple values, what I'd like to do is have a More Like This where any single post could show other posts that match one or more of the categories of the post.

UPDATE: Here's the code I'm using now, which I'm still not having any luck with:

```
the_field( 'aims'); /* since I'm on the page for a single post, this gives me the aims for the current post and is currently returning values from the checkbox with multiple selections (as an array, I believe) */


$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'program',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'aims',
            'value'     => 'Well-Being', /* I'd actually like this to use the aims for the current post, but I've hard-coded for testing, and am not seeing any results */
            'compare'   => 'IN')
        )); 

$more_like_this = new WP_Query ($args);
while ($more_like_this->have_posts()) : $more_like_this->the_post();

                $star_rating = get_field('overall_score'); 

                ?>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                <?php echo $star_rating ?>

                <?php endwhile; 
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
```

Comment: Save the array of arguments in a variable `$args` and then change `new WP_Query($posts);` to `new WP_Query($args);` . The array of arguments is `array('numberposts' => -1,.,.,.,.,.)));` Also, after having the `$args` variable you will have to change `$posts = ` to `$posts = get_posts($args);`. After doing those changes, make sure 1) `$posts` has a returned array with those posts. 2) That `$more_like_this` holds data.

Comment: Also don't forget to call `wp_reset_query()` after the `endwhile;`

Comment: Thanks for this, Antonis. I've updated the code above, but am still not getting any results. I've hard-coded the 'Well-Being', which I know has results, but I'd ultimately like to use the disorders array for the single post, which is currently returning data, and return a new set of posts with one or more of those same disorders matching. I know I'm close, but can't see what I'm missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a wp query to select some posts where multiple ACF checkbox options must be checked you can do like this:

```
// Get the array with selected options
$fields = get_field('somefield');

// First create the meta_query variable (AND can also be OR)
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
foreach( $fields as $field ){
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'name_of_acf_checkbox_here',
        'value'   => $aim,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
}

// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'postype_here',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```